# Words that contain other words but which aren't anagrams

Tags: ambiguity

What are words that contain other, often contradictory words or phrases, such as "manslaughter" ("man's laughter") or "therapist" ("the rapist")? I found "to get her" ("together") on another site. No anagrams, please.

Comment: How about "notarealquestion"?

Comment: Regdwightissogoingtoclosethis?

Comment: Bill, please see the faq (http://english.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: what was the question again? if you're looking for a list...where did you find the others?

Comment: kidsexchange (kids exchange)

Comment: Do you want to ask: "How are words called that..."? I think there was a name for those, but I forgot it. Sorry!