# Term for a word that is unintentionally made up of two or more other words?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

For example, *therapist* may be split into *the* + *rapist*, neither of which (arguably) has anything to do with the original words.

Another example would be *conflagration*: *con* + *flag* + *ration*. Or *weather*: *we* + *at* + *her*.

Note that words like *threesome* and *purebred* would not qualify, because the parts are intentional and contribute to the original word's meaning.

It seems to me there might be a word for this, which I would describe as "accidental lexical componentry" — but I'm not sure there is one. And if I do think of one I will be sure to add a *supplemental* (*supple* + *mental*) section (*sect* + *ion*) to this question (*quest* + *ion*).

Comment: I suppose you could say they were a kind of pun.

Comment: These serendipitous occurrences, whether single words in one interpretation or not, are much beloved of crossword compilers, lending themselves to wacky double definitions as they do. For example, _I'ts a near certainty he's a strange child_ (4,2) : odds on. _Distraught as a result of the music being played after midnight_ (12) : disconsolate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't think that's quite it, since the words produced are not made up of unrelated whole words.

Comment: _Disconsolate_ is, as is _advancement_ (for which I've forgotton a reasonable clue). (unrelated to the other reading rather than to other words in the string in the same reading, of course)

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of *sol*. Forgive me. Sometimes I need things spelled out. But how does *distraught* qualify?

Comment: Distraught=disconsolate. Disc+on+so+late = Music (on record) being played after midnight.

Comment: Which invites: is there a term for words / strings that can be analysed like this in **more** than two different ways?

Comment: Maybe they're lexidents (lexical accidents).

Comment: I don't think there's a special term; since it has to do only with the vagaries of English spelling, it's not something linguists are interested in. Maybe Will Shortz has a term for it.

Comment: I seem to remember seeing 'the rapist' before: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70994. (That poor therapist; methinks someone is out _to·get·her_.) When studying for a spelling bee, one could call these _mnemonics_.

Comment: @J.R.: Except this *is* a real question.

Comment: Necro-comment: Then there's *undoable*, which is a contronym depending on how you divide it: undo-able or un-doable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are called *[redividers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redivider)* or *redivided words*:

> (puzzles) A sequence of letters that can be segmented into two or more different sentences
>
> 2001, David B. Searls, “From Jabberwocky to Genome: Lewis Carroll and Computational Biology”, Journal of Computational Biology, volume 8, number 3, page 344:
> *Latter-day puzzle makers in a direct lineage from Carroll’s tradition and even more extreme instances of segmentation oddities in what are called **redividers** (Michaelsen, 1998), for example, observing that the sentence “**In every ode linger many**” can be resegmented to read “**I never yodel in Germany**” (Shortz, 1997); such cases serve to point out the duality of the problems of gap assignment and boundary detection, and also inject a combinatorial flavor.*

They are apparently also known as *charades*. Quoting from [The Dictionary of Wordplay by Dave Morice](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-dictionary-of-wordplay-dave-morice/1004508433):

> A few wordplay terms were especially problematic. Recently some writers have tried to upgrade some of the older, more traditional terminology. Some believe that pyramid should be replaced with triangle. **Some feel that redivider should replace charade.** The terms in the dictionary are usually those that have appeared most often in print. Any other terms may be listed as synonyms, or they may appear as separate entries with a brief notation that cross-references them to the older terms.

There are a number of domain names which have become infamous thanks to their ... redivisibility:

- therapistfinder.com
- penisland.com
- expertsexchange.com
- powergenitalia.com
- whorepresents.com

Answer (score 11):

As a humorous neologism, you might call them *polyparses*.

Comment: I think that term is already used [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrot_virtual_machine).  Or at least, it should be. :)

Comment: Let me point out for the humor-challenged that *polyparses* is an example of what Rob is asking about.

Comment: When the word in question is also a neologism, perhaps you could call it a "garden-path word".  I certainly had to re-read it.

Answer (score 8):

The terms *pun*, *false segmentation*, and *metanalysis* are used in discussion of the phenomenon in p. 132 of [Attardo's *Linguistic Theories of Humor*](http://books.google.com/books?id=FEWC4_3MrO0C&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=false%20morphological%20segmentation%20linguistics&source=bl&ots=MJxn0e0YKU&sig=vuOUD3_rG0kc8UzquEkyn085Lrk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5iPfUPuFD4OU2wWu-YCIDg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=false%20morphological%20segmentation%20linguistics&f=false), which cites several other works that might be worth consulting.