# What is a “big-ender pair”?

Tags: meaning, punctuation, computing, paraprosdokian

In the sci.math newsgroup ca. 23 Mar 2013, in thread *Subject: Re: math formulae?*, I saw the following:

> > >"Is the tournment liken to a bridge tournment?  The problem is vague.
>    > > As there are 100 diffenent bigender pairs, 10 rounds would be
>    >  > inadequate.
>
> > I can’t compare euchre to bridge, as I don’t know how the latter is
>    > played. In this particular euchre tournament, there are to be 5 tables,
>    > each seating 2 bigender pairs per round ...

Anyway, does anyone know what a *big-ender pair* is?  Also, it seems
to me to be incorrect to leave out the hyphen as those newsgroup
posters did.  For example, the wikipedia article on
*[Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-endian)* consistently
hyphenates big-endian, little-endian, etc.

Comment: Perhaps it's bi-gender.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross [A polyparse?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95939/term-for-a-word-that-is-unintentionally-made-up-of-two-or-more-other-words)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the rest of the [conversation](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=8740220) you refer to on mathforum.org. Based on the entire transcript, I think it is clear they are using *bigender* to mean pairs composed of one man and one woman, bi-gender as suggested by [St John of the Cross](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/39630/st-john-of-the-cross) (emphasis mine):

> I've been assigned a task which requires a level of mathematical/
>   computational skill which I do not have.
>
> There are 20 players - **10 men and 10 women** - participating in a euchre
>   tournament of 10 rounds at 5 tables. The objective is to have **each man
>   partner with each woman** once and play against each woman once, to have
>   the women all play against each other least once, to have the men all
>   play against each other least once, and to seat each player twice at
>   all 5 tables.

---

> Is the tournment liken to a bridge tournment? The problem is vague.
>   As there are 100 diffenent bigender pairs, 10 rounds would be inadequate.

Whether or not *bigender* is used correctly here is another issue.

Comment: In that case it should definitely be bi-gender.