# Is there a term for a compound word that may be split in multiple places?

Tags: terminology

The only example I can currently think of is from the Spawn comic book. The compound word “Hellspawn” may be split two different ways:

- Hell spawn (creature born of Hell)
- Hell’s pawn (a minor figure manipulated by more powerful demons)

I am searching for other words similar to Hellspawn but not so, well, Hellish. I’d like to use a similar play on words. Knowing the term would improve my search.

Hellspawn above is a cheat, in that the apostrophe is implied. I’d like to find a word without such a cheat.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95939/2303)

Comment: [This one too](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226856/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-when-you-break-a-word-in-a-different-place-to-give)

Comment: A superset of these (where one reading may be just a free combination, a non-collocated phrase) comprise a favourite of crossword compilers. I've a book listing types of clue somewhere, but I think it will only give a hypernym (if that). _It's a virtual certainty that he's a strange child (4,2)_ is one of the larger set.

Comment: @Justin is right; possible duplicate of [Term for a word that is unintentionally made up of two or more other words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95939/term-for-a-word-that-is-unintentionally-made-up-of-two-or-more-other-words) (where coleopterist dredges up 'redivider', and others other terms (eg 'false segmentation'). Only the same answers would occur here. And I must find some different crosswords to do.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like saying "Godspeed" can be "God speed" or "Gods peed"?

Yeah, there's a word for that. "Gods peed" would be a homophone of "Godspeed," but there's not a specific word or term for a compound word that has been erroneously split as if it were a compound of different words then it actually is a compound of.

Also, when a compound word arises out of a possessive case, the apostrophe is eliminated, examples include "wolfsbane" from "wolf's bane" and "monkshood" from "monk's hood."

Comment: ""Gods peed"?" OMG I can't believe you wrote that.