# Term for new or inappropriate phrases that appear when you remove the spaces between words?

Tags: terminology, humor, obscure-terms

I'm looking for a term, if it exists at all, that describes a new word or phrase that appears when you remove the spaces from a phrase.

Lots of websites have fallen into this trap, for example:

Old Man's Haven —> oldmanshaven.com

Who Represents —> whorepresents.com

Comment: Some may be intentional, some not. Pen Island: intentional. PowerGen Italia: accidental. Never heard of a term for it, though.

Comment: Originally, Experts-Exchange.com did not have a hyphen in their URL.  But I don't have a name for it either.

Comment: Polysemic compounds, of course.

Comment: See also [linguistics.se]

Comment: Btw, is *incre* a word?

Comment: Thanks all, I looked up polysemic compounds and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Then please try https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=polysemic+compounds&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB779GB779&oq=polysemic+compounds&aqs=chrome..69i57.1069j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Term for a word that is unintentionally made up of two or more other words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95939/term-for-a-word-that-is-unintentionally-made-up-of-two-or-more-other-words)

Comment: Just look up Sean Connery on Celebrity Jeopardy.... "The Pen is Mightier"... "An Album Cover" just to name a few...